# Initializing and storing a random number on inital app load CakePHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session, cakephp

I'm currently learning the basics of CakePHP (I've also done the tutorials on cake's site)

I'm looking to better understand how Cake talks to parts of the app.
Basically I'm looking to generate a random number on load and store it in a session. What file in cake do I initialize and store my random number in? This number after generated must stay static throughout page loads, until manually changed or the website closes.

MyController.php

```
function beforeFilter() {
$this->Session->write('Random.Num', rand(1,10)); 
}
```

Obviously I can't do this in my controller as my example shows, the number keeps changing on every page view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have condition to check session first before wrting to it,

```
if (!$this->Session->check('Random.Num')) {
    $this->Session->write('Random.Num', rand(1,10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `Random.Num` if it is not yet initialized like this

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if(!isset($this->Session->read('Random.Num')))
    $this->Session->write('Random.Num', rand(1,10)); 
}
```

Comment: This is not valid PHP (isset cannot use methods in current PHP versions).